# Java best practice for error checking in abstract methods

Tags: java, abstract

I'm learning java and right now I'm learning to work with a superclass.
I have this superclass with an abstract method. When I make subclasses, I have to implement these methods. The 'problem' is that each implementation shares some code. (the exception throwing).
I was wondering if there is a better way to write this code? Or is this already best practice?

Here is my code now:

```
public abstract class Sugar{
    abstract  calculateprice(int weight);
}


public class LiquidSugar extends Sugar{
    public double  calculateprice(int weight){
        if(weight<0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("weight cannot be zero");
        }
        return 'complex formula to calculate price';
    }
}

public class Sugar1 extends Sugar{
    public double  calculateprice(int weight){
        if(weight<0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("weight cannot be zero");
        }
        return 'another complex formula to calculate price';
    }
}

public class Sugar2 extends Sugar{
    public double calculateprice(int weight){
        if(weight<0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("weight cannot be zero");
        }
        return 'another complex formula to calculate price';
    }
}
```

I know I could write a method in the superClass like this:

```
public double calculatePriceSuper(int weight){
    if(weight<0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("weight cannot be zero");
    }
    return calculateprice(weight);
}
```

And do all the error checking in the superclass "wrapper" method. But is that really better?

Comment: java best practice is to add semicolons to terminate statements

Comment: Yes, it is better :)

Comment: In this case, since the `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown for the same identical condition and states the same message for all child classes, it makes a lot of sense to have the base implementation in the base class (hence, a non `abstract` method that is then overridden by the child classes).

Comment: You say "a non abstract method that is then overridden by the child classes", why should I overwrite it in my childclass? If it's the same check for every childClass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pull the check in to its own method:

```
protected void validateWeight( int weight ) {
    if(weight<0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("weight cannot be zero");
    }
}
```

and then you can reuse it like this

```
public double calOne modeling mistake that you may be at risk of here is misuse of inheritence. Unfortunately there are many OO tutorials that teach that a bird extends an animal which extends a thculatePriceSuper(int weight){
    validateWeight(weight);
    return calculateprice(weight);
}
```

> But is that really better?

When the logic that is being repeated is truely identical, and not just circumstantial then yes this approach is significantly better.  It reduces clutter, and means that if a change is required to the validation of weight then it only needs to be made in one place.  Every time code is duplicated, we have one more place to maintain and opportunities for behaviour to diverge.

However this can become bad when the use of the shared code is only circumstantially similar.  That is where different checks may be required that are not needed everywhere.  Spotting the difference takes time and experience, but don't be afraid to go for it here.

---

Additional

One modeling mistake that you may be at risk of here is a misuse of inheritence; there is not enough context here for me to be sure.  Unfortunately there are many OO tutorials that teach that a bird extends an animal which extends a thing etc.  Unfortunately that becomes very rigid when modeling, especially in a single inheritance language such as Java. Sub classing by types of sugar sounds like a similar problem to me.  You would probably benefit from using delegation instead, ie have a single Sugar class and then use the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) or similar to enhance the behaviour of calculating price.  Depending on your domain model, the class type may even be best as 'Product', 'Commodity' or even 'Priceable' or PriceCalculator.  But you are the best just of that.